# Getting an error when using prepared statement in python

Tags: python, mysql

whenever I try to run a normal query all works perfectly fine. the code executes and I can get the results but whenever I try to use a prepared statement in python I keep getting the following error:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE name = ?' at line 1
```

The code I'm trying to run:

```
cursor = con.db.cursor(prepared=True)
try:
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE name = %s", ('operations', 'check', ))
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
   print(error)
except TypeError as e:
   print(e)
```

I've tried also to change the tuple object to string and removed one of the '%s' just for checking. but I still get an error for the '%s' synax.

another thing I've tried is to use a dict object so I've changed the '%s' to '%(table)s' and '%(name)s' and used a dict of

```
{'table': 'operations', 'name': 'check'}
```

example:

```
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %(table)s WHERE name = %(name)s", {'table': 'operations', 'name': 'check'})
```

but again it didn't worked and I still got the exception

am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

-------- Edit --------

Thanks to @khelwood, I've fixed the problem.
as @khelwood mentioned in comments the problem was because I tried to use the '%s' as a parameter for table name.
python prepared statements can't handle parameters for things such as table names
so thats what throwed the exception

Comment: You can't insert a table name as a query parameter. You can pass the name you're looking for as a parameter, but it should be in a tuple: `("check",)`

Comment: @JailtonSilva The `,` is correct when you're passing query parameters to `cursor.execute`.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: @khelwood You were right, the problem was because I tried to insert the table name as a parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert a table name as a query parameter. You can pass the name you're looking for as a parameter, but it should be in a tuple: `("check",)`

So

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM operations WHERE name = %s", ("check", ))
```